SwiftUI: TextField automatically scrolls to the bottom when tapped for longer text
When adding long enough text to a vertical TextField into a Section of a List, it scrolls all the way to the bottom of the TextField when tapped. This happens even if it means that the cursor/caret is hidden.
The goal is to just scroll down to where the cursor is. We also want to allow the TextField to grow beyond the size of the screen, and we could just scroll down the List to view what's needed.
I've tried using a ScrollViewReader and using proxy.scrollTo with various anchors, but nothing seems to prevent it from scrolling all the way to the bottom.
Here is code that produces the behavior:
import SwiftUI

struct LongTextFieldView: View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Text") {
                TextField("Placeholder text", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
            }
        }
        .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)
    }
}

Here is what it looks like before you tap into the TextField.
Before
Here is what it looks like after you tap into the TextField. You're sent all the way to the bottom, even if you tapped onto the first line.
After
